# If value in pandas dataframe equals value in other dataframe replace value with other column value from 2nd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = {'ID': [3,0,1,0], 'Other': [GTT, CTT, ATT, TTT]}

df2 = {'ID': [0,1,2,3], 'ACC': [A, B, C, D]}
```

They are also not the same size. df1 (8412x13) and df2 (3652x2)

I need to replace the values in df1['ID'] with the 'ACC' from the second dataframe if df1['ID'] equals df2['ID'].

So it needs to look like this:

```
df1 = {'ID': [C, A, B, A], 'Other': [GTT, CTT, ATT, TTT]}
```

I have tried using the update and replace function but those solutions often have the same 'denominator' column, which this doesn't have. I also tried creating a dictionary of df2, however, it seems the dataframe is too large to use df2.to_dict().

Comment: `df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['ACC'])`

Comment: @Quang Hoang This is an answer, please post as such. Makes it easier to avoid wasting time on already answered questions.

Comment: @AndersKällmar I don't post it as the answer as this most likely is a duplicate.

Comment: @Quang Hoang Good point!

Comment: @QuangHoang This doesn't really work because both dataframes have different sizes. This is because some 'ID' are duplicates. These duplicates need to have the same 'ACC', however, right now they get the next 'ACC'. This leaves the df1['ID'] with 3000+ NaN's. Any idea how to fix this?